# Can a sport field not surrounded by seats be called an arena?

Tags: meaning

I found the following definitions of the word ‘Arena’:

- 1)   A large, flat area surrounded by seats used for sports or entertainment (dictionary.cambridge.org)
- 2)   A level area surrounded by seating, in which sports, entertainments, and other public events are held. (en.oxforddictionaries.com)

My question is as follows: Can a sport field (e.g. cricket or soccer) be called an arena if it is not surrounded by seats and there is no space for an audience?
All other definitions I have found specify that an arena must have seats for spectators.

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Comment: It's a place where sports (etc) are _presented_.

Comment: What if it is a field and people bring their own chairs (or sit on the ground)?  If the definition requires seating, does that qualify to turn a field into an arena?

Comment: "arena" can be used figuratively as you can find in Meriam-Websters 3a :  a sphere of interest, activity, or competition the political arena
3b :  a place or situation for controversy in the public arena https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arena     ... So, I could see using arena interchangeably with "venue" if you had to.  I think for the most part though, what people would envision was a large venue surrounded by seats.  "can you?" and "is it the best word for my situation?" are two different questions.

Comment: See definition 3 in [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/arena): "3.  The area in the center of an ancient Roman amphitheater where contests and other spectacles were held" This area was strewn with sand, so you could make a strong case for no seats necessary for an arena for a beach volleyball game ( :) ), but I agree with @Tom22 that people expect seats in an arena and calling a venue with no seating an arena is not the best choice of words.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the original ***arena*** has undergone both semantic drift and metaphorical extension.  Initially, it meant *that part of an amphitheater in which the events took place*, and which was surrounded by tiers of seats.  Later, it was used in the sense of the amphitheater as a whole, and has now virtually replaced that term in general use.  This can be seen in the entry for "arena" in  [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arena):

> 1 :  an area in a Roman amphitheater for gladiatorial combats
>
> 2 a :  an enclosed area used for public entertainment
>
> 2 b :  a building containing an arena
>
> 3    a :  a sphere of interest, activity, or competition the political
> arena
>
> 3    b :  a place or situation for controversy in the public arena

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/10532?redirectedFrom=arena#eid) (which conflates M-W 1 and 2 in its own entry) does provide dates for the earliest occurrence of each sense, with 1 [original sense] dating from 1627, 2 [shifted sense] dating from 1812, and (virtually simultaneously) 3 [metaphorical sense] dating from 1814.

While Merriam-Webster isn't entirely clear as to whether a venue described as an arena must contain seats, consulting the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) might help.  There, there are 200+ instances of "sports arena", quite enough to provide material to garner a sense of the range of contemporary uses of "arena".